# how to blur multiple objects at the same time using swift

Tags: ios, swift, blur

I have used the code as below. But it only blur one position. Now I want to blur multiple positions at once

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func btn_blur(_ sender: Any) {
        // 1
        let darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        // 2
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)
        blurView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 50, height: 50)
        // 3
        imageView.addSubview(blurView)

    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but can you add more `blurView`s with different frames to your `imageView` ?

Comment: I will get the result returned from the server as a 2-dimensional array of values [[x, y, w, h], [x, y, w, h]]. and then blur. If too many views will not guarantee speed

Comment: Store the array that you get from the server as a property of your view controller, and then you can access it in `btn_blur()` to create your views.

Comment: How can I add multiple frames to the same image? can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store an array of frames in your view controller, and fill that with your server response. Then use those frames to create the blur views.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var frames = [CGRect]() // load this from your server data

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func btn_blur(_ sender: Any) {
        let darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)

        for frame in frames {
           let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)
           blurView.frame = frame

           imageView.addSubview(blurView)
        }
    }
}
```